# Сортировка массива объектов

Tags: массивы, java

Есть свой класс `A` с одним из полей `String p`. в программе создается массив `A arr[] = new A[n]`.    
Можно ли создать такой метод класса `A`, чтобы сортировать массив элементов этого класса по полю `p`.
То есть интересует, чтоб вызов функции был вида `arr.sort();`, но обращение было к функции `sort` класса `A`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ваш класс `A` может реализовать интерфейс `java.lang.Comparable` и в методе `compareTo` сравнивать свой экземпляр с другим экземпляром.

После чего вы смело можете пользоваться  методом `sort` из класса `Arrays`.

Answer (score 3):

Сам в этой области чайник. Поэтому думаю, что совершенно верный ответ [@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate) может быть полезно подкрепить конкретным примером.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortTest {
    public static void main (String [] av) {
        A [] arr = new A[4];
        arr[0] = new A(12,"x12");
        arr[1] = new A(16,"x16");
        arr[2] = new A(1,"x1");
        arr[3] = new A(62,"x62");
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (A a : arr)
            System.out.println(a);
    }
}

class A implements Comparable {
    private int    p;
    private String s;
    A() {}
    A(int v, String b) {
        p = v;
        s = b;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg) {
        return p - ((A)arg).p;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return p+"=> "+s;
    }   
}
```

Сам только учусь Java. Поэтому (**вот и вопрос к знатокам - почему ?**) arr.sort() не получилось, Eclipse говорит: нет такого метода для arr. (А может так и нельзя писать ? Всего сразу не упомнить).  Поэтому Arrays.sort(arr);

Comment: Как я понял sort для класса Arrays определен как static поэтому вызов через класс.

Comment: просто для массивов как таковых в Java не определен метод сортировки. Зато все вспомогательные плюшки по работе с массивами собраны в класс Arrays. Естественно все методы static, так как класс чисто утилитарный, поэтому создавать экземпляр класса Arrays не надо.